# Does $\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$ really equal to $\log(A)-\log(B)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I was investigating the laws of logarithm and playing with Desmos when I realized something curious.

The example equation is $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{2x-4}{6x-8}\right)$ and the graph is this:

[image]

The law of logarithms say that: $\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)=\log(A)-\log(B)$

Graphing $f(x)=\log(2x-4)-\log(6x-8)$ however shows this:

[image]

While the right side of the domain is preserved, the left side of the domain isn't preserved. The reason I thought of is because logs can never take negative values and while $\log(A)-\log(B)$ excludes cases where the numerator and denominator are negative, $\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$ doesn't because $\left(\frac{-A}{-B}\right)=+C$.

However, one thing I noticed is that lots if not all resources about laws of logarithms never mention how some domains will be added/removed if you use this property. I question if this equivalency is still accurate?

Comment: So long as $A/B,A,$ and $B$ are all within the domain of the logarithm, yes you have $\log(A/B)=\log(A)-\log(B)$.  As soon as you start going outside of that, as you have noticed things can go awry.  Any rigorous description of the "laws of logarithm" will emphasize this point.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$?  Because the situation with complex logarithms is more...complex.

Comment: @Dan Yep, but now I'm now curious on how complex logarithms work, so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @JustKirb: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136570/determination-of-complex-logarithm/136659

Comment: @JMoravitz I read more sources and realized on how proofs carefully assume A>0 and B>0 so the equality holds true as it never claims to work for cases where A or B are negative, so thanks for your answer.

Comment: This [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BLog%5B2+x+-+4%5D+-+Log%5B6+x+-+8%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%5D) illustrates there seems to be a problem with Desmos as the imaginary parts of $\log(2x−4)$ and $−\log(6x−8)$ cancel each other out for $x\in\mathbb{R}\land x\notin\left[\frac{4}{3},2\right]$.